# Replacing constant with variable of the same value and type, causes different results

Tags: c, type-conversion

```
int main()
{
    int nodes = 7;

    int var_1 = (int)(log((double)(nodes + 1))/log(2) - 1);
    int var_2 = (int)(log((double)(7 + 1))/log(2) - 1);

    printf("%d\n", var_1);
    printf("%d\n", var_2);

    return 0;
}
```

The above code initializes the varialbes `var_1` and `var_2` to values 1 and 2, accordingly.

Why they have different values since the variable `nodes` has the value of 7, same as the constant in the next equation.

Edit: I dont try to "fix" the code, or else I could just assign `nodes+1` to a variable.

Comment: When I run it I get the same result for both - 2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first statement is probably calculated at runtime by the code pre-compiled in the standard library (with libm), the second statement is probably calculated at compile time by the compiler (with MPFR).

Probably `log(8)` by *libm* is a tiny little bit less than by *MPFR*.

```
2.079441541...7 / 0.69314... = 2.999999...
2.079441541...8 / 0.69314... = 3.000000...
```

Comment: So if I understand correctly, the probelm has to do with the compiler Im using? If I run the code using different compiler I might get the correct result?

Comment: Don't just chop off decimals when converting double to int: do some rounding instead eg with (probably not right, I am not a number scientist): `(int)(doubleval + 0.5)`